# TeamDrive in Google Drive API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm trying the code below, obtained from their docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-teamdrives). I'm unable to compile, I get an exception message:

[image]

Maybe I'm not understanding the TeamDrive concept correctly?

I'm not sure where the issue is. Below is the code snippet I have:

```
        var teamDriveMetadata = new TeamDrive()
        {
            Name = "Project Resources"
        };

        var requestId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var request = service.Teamdrives.Create(teamDriveMetadata, requestId);
        request.Fields = "id";

        var teamDrive = request.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Team Drive ID: " + teamDrive.Id);

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.Read();
```

Below is the auth setup:

```
        using (var stream =
          new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
              System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
              GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
              Scopes,
              "MyKey",
              CancellationToken.None,
              new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        });
```

Comment: Check how your app handle authorization before running your code.
 [Teamdrives: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/teamdrives/create) need [authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/teamdrives/create#auth) to run the request. I've tried using the "Try this API" for `Teamdrives: create` and managed to create a new Team Drive.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, I just added the setup for authorization currently in my code. I get "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file." when using the "Try this API".

Comment: @Mr.Rebot , how did you use the "Try this API"? I've set the requestId, and set the name property of the teamDrive body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: I ran the sample code linked without issue.  I have a test project that has the proper permissions already established.  I pasted the linked code into that project, and had to resolve "*var request*" conflicting with the same in my existing code.  Once resolved the code ran without issue.

As previously suggested I would recommend focusing on resolving your permissions/scopes.